# Sending emails to the same address via Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I have several records which have same emails address. When I launch my journey, just only for one record email sends, for others -  journey show 'error'. How can I send emails for all records with same email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the entry data extension send/subscriber relationship to be on a unique ID that is not the email address.
This way the subscriber can be matched on each subscriber's ID and send to the same email address.
Deduplication happens on the subscriber key level.